# jOOQ fetch OneToOne though reference side

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I want to fetch a User object like that:

```java
record User(
    UUID id,
    String username,
    String ipAddress,
    long lastJoinAt,
    long createdAt,
    long updatedAt,
    GuildMembersRecord guildMember
) {}

record GuildMembersRecord(
    UUID id,
    UUID guildId,
    UUID userId,
    String role,
    OffsetDateTime updatedAt
    OffsetDateTime createdAt,
) {}
```

My problem is that the guildmember is always null, but I can find it when i'm searching it separatly. The guild member is the owning side and my user is the reference side. I'm trying to get the guild member by using the reference side.

My query is like that:

```java
UUID key = UUID.randomUUID();
this.context.select(
    USERS.ID,
    USERS.USERNAME,
    USERS.IP_ADDRESS,
    USERS.LAST_JOIN_AT,
    USERS.CREATED_AT,
    USERS.UPDATED_AT,
        row(
        DSL.select(GUILD_MEMBERS)
        .from(GUILD_MEMBERS)
        .where(GUILD_MEMBERS.USER_ID.eq(key))
    ).convertFrom(r -> r.into(GUILD_MEMBERS).into(GuildMembersRecord.class))
)
.from(USERS)
.where(USERS.ID.eq(key))
.fetchOne(Records.mapping(User::new))
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to a recent [support request #14174](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14174), where a user was looking for a way to map a single record using `row(Select)`. It seems that this would be a reasonable thing to expect, analogous to the [`multiset(Select)` value constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/), but just like this isn't available in standard SQL, it's not available in jOOQ in this particular form.

The simplest option is to just turn the `Select` into a [scalar correlated subquery](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/scalar-subqueries/), using [`field(Select<R>):Field<R>`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Select)):

```java
field(
    select(GUILD_MEMBERS)
    .from(GUILD_MEMBERS)
    .where(GUILD_MEMBERS.USER_ID.eq(key))
)
```

Note that in this case, no [ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) or record mapping is required, since you're already [projecting the entire table reference](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/) `GUILD_MEMBERS`, which produces the expected `GuildMembersRecord`